# how to link variables so when i modify one of them both are modified? or just the top level one

Tags: variables, kotlin

I have 3 variables A,b and c in a class called ONE

```
var a = 0
var b = 0
var c = 0
```

that class(class ONE) is abstract and is used by 3 classes(TWO, THREE, FOUR). the variable selected changes by using a when statement.

```
var chosenVariable:Long
        chosenVariable= when (sign){
            1-> a
            2-> b
            3-> c
            else -> a
        }
```

note that sign is what the user inputs to decide which variable is chosen.

my question is. when i modify `chosenVariable` I want it to change whatever variable it was set a, b or c.

is this possible? I thought it might be called instancing, but I can't seem to come up with anything searching that way. I think i need to do it somehow with a setter and getter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `KMutableProperty0<>` class to hold reference to primitive variables:

```
var chosenVariable: KMutableProperty0<Long> = when (sign) {
        1-> ::a
        2-> ::b
        3-> ::c
        else -> ::a
}

// set value
chosenVariable.set(7)
```

It is currently available only for global variables. [Here is some useful info](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/pass-by-ref-for-inline-functions/4805/27).

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this out and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `chosenVariable` is the `sign`, either:

there can be another function to set/get chosen variables (`a`, `b`, `c`), such as:

```
var chosenVariable : Long = 0 // init value

fun set ( value : Int ) {
    when ( chosenVariable ) {
        // 1 -> a = value
        2 -> b = value
        3 -> c = value
        else -> a = value
    }
}
fun get ( ) {
    return when ( chosenVariable ) {
        // 1 -> a
        2 -> b
        3 -> c
        else -> a
    }
}
```

or maybe use MutableMap instead:

```
val variables = mutableMapOf <Long /* sign */, Int /* value */> (
    1 to 0, // a
    2 to 0, // b
    3 to 0, // c
)

// still with getter/setter like before, but with map
fun get ( ) = variables [ chosenVariable ]
fun set ( value : Int ) {
    variables [ chosenVariable ] = value
}
```

Comment: sorry! sign is what the user inputs to decide which variable is chosen. they give a "sign" and then a variable is chosen (chosenVariable) based on that sign. I updated my question with the extra info

Comment: @sourlemonaid do you mean `chosenVariable` is of same reference of either `a`, `b`, or `c`? when `chosenVariable` is modified, either `a`, `b`, or `c` is modified at same time?

Comment: exactly! I didn't know that was called a reference